# How to put past dates from core data at the bottom of uitableview?

Tags: swift, core-data

I have a tableview that sorts core data by date in ascending order and I would like to put the dates that have already passed at the bottom of the tableview.

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Reminder> = Reminder.fetchRequest()
    let sort = NSSortDescriptor(key: #keyPath(Reminder.date), ascending: true)
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sort]
    let reminders = try! PersistenceController.context.fetch(fetchRequest)
    self.remindersArray = reminders
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as? MainTableViewCell
    cell!.titleLabel.text = remindersArray[indexPath.row].title
    cell!.dateLabel.text = DateAssist.DateToString(remindersArray[indexPath.row].date!)
    cell!.timeLabel.text = DateAssist.TimeToString(remindersArray[indexPath.row].date!)
    //        }
    return cell!
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible workaround if your data set isn't to large is to sort the array after the fetch instead of using a sort descriptor.

Add the following function to your Reminder class

```
extension Reminder {
    func isAfter(_ date: Date) -> Bool {
        return self.date > date
    }
}
```

and then sort the array like

```
    let self.remindersArray = reminders.sorted(by: { 
        let now = Date()
        if $0.isAfter(now) == $1.isAfter(now) {
            return $0.date < $1.date
        }
        return $0.isAfter(now) 
    })
```